# React Native Router Flux (react-native-router-flux) - call action in reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

i have a question about calling an action from a reducer or just to redirect to another scene. I want to redirect to a scene after the user is succesfully logged in. I have my action.js which use the 'redux-api-middleware' module:

action.js

```
export const LOGIN_REQUEST = 'LOGIN_REQUEST';
export const LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL = 'LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL';
export const LOGIN_FAILED = 'LOGIN_FAILED';

export function login(data) {
  return {
    [CALL_API]: {
      endpoint: API_ROOT + 'login',
      method: 'POST',
      types: [LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL, LOGIN_FAILED],
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
  }
}
```

reducer.js

```
function login(state = initalstate, action){

  switch (action.type) {

    case LOGIN_REQUEST:

        return {
            ...state,
          isFetching: true
        };

    case LOGIN_FAILED:

        return {
            ...state,
          error: action.error,
          isFetching: false
        };

    case LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL:

        return {
            ...state,
          error: null,
          isFetching: false
        };  

      break;

    default:
      return state;

  }

}
```

Now if I get `LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL` I want to call an action like ActionsMY_SCENE_KEY to redirect to the next screen. I get some errors when I call the Actions in the reducer and this is probably the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should not trigger action with your reducer. 
You have 2 otpions:

1) When your user successfully logs in, you can reflect that in your state:

```
case LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL:

    return {
        ...state,
      error: null,
      isFetching: false,
      loggedIn: true,
    };
```

That way in your container connected to your state, you can check this state.loggedIn value and trigger the transition accordingly by dispatching your transition action.

2) When you are handling the login API response, on a successful reply, you can simply dispatch your transition scene action to redirect to the next screen (you can combine this with your successful login action dispatch).